# The specified module could not be found: QTJambi

Tags: java, qt, qtquick2, qt6, qtquick-designer

I decided to use [QTJambi](https://github.com/OmixVisualization/qtjambi) for my first QT project. After reading Wiki, I started to install this library. Here is tree of my `Qt\6.1.0\msvc2019_64\bin` folder:

```
C:\QT\6.1.0\MSVC2019_64\BIN
│   androiddeployqt.exe
│   androiddeployqt.pdb
│   androidtestrunner.exe
│   androidtestrunner.pdb
│   android_emulator_launcher.sh
│   assistant.exe
│   assistant.pdb
│   balsam.pdb
│   cmake_automoc_parser.exe
│   cmake_automoc_parser.pdb
│   d3dcompiler_47.dll
│   designer.exe
│   designer.pdb
│   dumpcpp.exe
│   dumpdoc.exe
│   ensure_pro_file.cmake
│   idc.exe
│   lconvert.exe
│   lconvert.pdb
│   licheck.exe
│   linguist.exe
│   linguist.pdb
│   lprodump.exe
│   lprodump.pdb
│   lrelease-pro.exe
│   lrelease-pro.pdb
│   lrelease.exe
│   lrelease.pdb
│   lupdate-pro.exe
│   lupdate-pro.pdb
│   lupdate.exe
│   lupdate.pdb
│   meshdebug.pdb
│   moc.exe
│   moc.pdb
│   opengl32sw.dll
│   pixeltool.exe
│   pixeltool.pdb
│   qdbus.exe
│   qdbus.pdb
│   qdbuscpp2xml.exe
│   qdbuscpp2xml.pdb
│   qdbusviewer.exe
│   qdbusviewer.pdb
│   qdbusxml2cpp.exe
│   qdbusxml2cpp.pdb
│   qdistancefieldgenerator.exe
│   qdistancefieldgenerator.pdb
│   qdoc.exe
│   qdoc.pdb
│   qhelpgenerator.exe
│   qhelpgenerator.pdb
│   qlalr.exe
│   qlalr.pdb
│   qmake.exe
│   qmake.pdb
│   qmake6.exe
│   qml.exe
│   qml.pdb
│   qmlcachegen.exe
│   qmlcachegen.pdb
│   qmleasing.exe
│   qmleasing.pdb
│   qmlformat.exe
│   qmlformat.pdb
│   qmlimportscanner.exe
│   qmlimportscanner.pdb
│   qmllint.exe
│   qmllint.pdb
│   qmlplugindump.exe
│   qmlplugindump.pdb
│   qmlpreview.exe
│   qmlpreview.pdb
│   qmlprofiler.exe
│   qmlprofiler.pdb
│   qmlscene.exe
│   qmlscene.pdb
│   qmltestrunner.exe
│   qmltestrunner.pdb
│   qmltime.exe
│   qmltime.pdb
│   qmltyperegistrar.exe
│   qmltyperegistrar.pdb
│   qsb.exe
│   qsb.pdb
│   qscxmlc.exe
│   qscxmlc.pdb
│   qt-cmake-private-install.cmake
│   qt-cmake-private.bat
│   qt-cmake-standalone-test.bat
│   qt-cmake.bat
│   qt-configure-module.bat
│   qt-internal-configure-tests.bat
│   Qt63DAnimation.dll
│   Qt63DAnimation.pdb
│   Qt63DAnimationd.dll
│   Qt63DAnimationd.pdb
│   Qt63DCore.dll
│   Qt63DCore.pdb
│   Qt63DCored.dll
│   Qt63DCored.pdb
│   Qt63DExtras.dll
│   Qt63DExtras.pdb
│   Qt63DExtrasd.dll
│   Qt63DExtrasd.pdb
│   Qt63DInput.dll
│   Qt63DInput.pdb
│   Qt63DInputd.dll
│   Qt63DInputd.pdb
│   Qt63DLogic.dll
│   Qt63DLogic.pdb
│   Qt63DLogicd.dll
│   Qt63DLogicd.pdb
│   Qt63DQuick.dll
│   Qt63DQuick.pdb
│   Qt63DQuickAnimation.dll
│   Qt63DQuickAnimation.pdb
│   Qt63DQuickAnimationd.dll
│   Qt63DQuickAnimationd.pdb
│   Qt63DQuickd.dll
│   Qt63DQuickd.pdb
│   Qt63DQuickExtras.dll
│   Qt63DQuickExtras.pdb
│   Qt63DQuickExtrasd.dll
│   Qt63DQuickExtrasd.pdb
│   Qt63DQuickInput.dll
│   Qt63DQuickInput.pdb
│   Qt63DQuickInputd.dll
│   Qt63DQuickInputd.pdb
│   Qt63DQuickRender.dll
│   Qt63DQuickRender.pdb
│   Qt63DQuickRenderd.dll
│   Qt63DQuickRenderd.pdb
│   Qt63DQuickScene2D.dll
│   Qt63DQuickScene2D.pdb
│   Qt63DQuickScene2Dd.dll
│   Qt63DQuickScene2Dd.pdb
│   Qt63DRender.dll
│   Qt63DRender.pdb
│   Qt63DRenderd.dll
│   Qt63DRenderd.pdb
│   Qt6Bodymovin.dll
│   Qt6Bodymovin.pdb
│   Qt6Bodymovind.dll
│   Qt6Bodymovind.pdb
│   Qt6Charts.dll
│   Qt6Charts.pdb
│   Qt6Chartsd.dll
│   Qt6Chartsd.pdb
│   Qt6Coap.pdb
│   Qt6Coapd.pdb
│   Qt6Concurrent.dll
│   Qt6Concurrent.pdb
│   Qt6Concurrentd.dll
│   Qt6Concurrentd.pdb
│   Qt6Core.dll
│   Qt6Core.pdb
│   Qt6Core5Compat.dll
│   Qt6Core5Compat.pdb
│   Qt6Core5Compatd.dll
│   Qt6Core5Compatd.pdb
│   Qt6Cored.dll
│   Qt6Cored.pdb
│   Qt6DataVisualization.dll
│   Qt6DataVisualization.pdb
│   Qt6DataVisualizationd.dll
│   Qt6DataVisualizationd.pdb
│   Qt6DBus.dll
│   Qt6DBus.pdb
│   Qt6DBusd.dll
│   Qt6DBusd.pdb
│   Qt6Designer.dll
│   Qt6Designer.pdb
│   Qt6DesignerComponents.dll
│   Qt6DesignerComponents.pdb
│   Qt6DesignerComponentsd.dll
│   Qt6DesignerComponentsd.pdb
│   Qt6Designerd.dll
│   Qt6Designerd.pdb
│   Qt6Gui.dll
│   Qt6Gui.pdb
│   Qt6Guid.dll
│   Qt6Guid.pdb
│   Qt6Help.dll
│   Qt6Help.pdb
│   Qt6Helpd.dll
│   Qt6Helpd.pdb
│   Qt6LabsAnimation.dll
│   Qt6LabsAnimation.pdb
│   Qt6LabsAnimationd.dll
│   Qt6LabsAnimationd.pdb
│   Qt6LabsFolderListModel.dll
│   Qt6LabsFolderListModel.pdb
│   Qt6LabsFolderListModeld.dll
│   Qt6LabsFolderListModeld.pdb
│   Qt6LabsQmlModels.dll
│   Qt6LabsQmlModels.pdb
│   Qt6LabsQmlModelsd.dll
│   Qt6LabsQmlModelsd.pdb
│   Qt6LabsSettings.dll
│   Qt6LabsSettings.pdb
│   Qt6LabsSettingsd.dll
│   Qt6LabsSettingsd.pdb
│   Qt6LabsSharedImage.dll
│   Qt6LabsSharedImage.pdb
│   Qt6LabsSharedImaged.dll
│   Qt6LabsSharedImaged.pdb
│   Qt6LabsWavefrontMesh.dll
│   Qt6LabsWavefrontMesh.pdb
│   Qt6LabsWavefrontMeshd.dll
│   Qt6LabsWavefrontMeshd.pdb
│   Qt6Mqtt.pdb
│   Qt6Mqttd.pdb
│   Qt6Network.dll
│   Qt6Network.pdb
│   Qt6NetworkAuth.dll
│   Qt6NetworkAuth.pdb
│   Qt6NetworkAuthd.dll
│   Qt6NetworkAuthd.pdb
│   Qt6Networkd.dll
│   Qt6Networkd.pdb
│   Qt6OpcUa.pdb
│   Qt6OpcUad.pdb
│   Qt6OpenGL.dll
│   Qt6OpenGL.pdb
│   Qt6OpenGLd.dll
│   Qt6OpenGLd.pdb
│   Qt6OpenGLWidgets.dll
│   Qt6OpenGLWidgets.pdb
│   Qt6OpenGLWidgetsd.dll
│   Qt6OpenGLWidgetsd.pdb
│   Qt6PrintSupport.dll
│   Qt6PrintSupport.pdb
│   Qt6PrintSupportd.dll
│   Qt6PrintSupportd.pdb
│   Qt6Qml.dll
│   Qt6Qml.pdb
│   Qt6Qmld.dll
│   Qt6Qmld.pdb
│   Qt6QmlLocalStorage.dll
│   Qt6QmlLocalStorage.pdb
│   Qt6QmlLocalStoraged.dll
│   Qt6QmlLocalStoraged.pdb
│   Qt6QmlModels.dll
│   Qt6QmlModels.pdb
│   Qt6QmlModelsd.dll
│   Qt6QmlModelsd.pdb
│   Qt6QmlWorkerScript.dll
│   Qt6QmlWorkerScript.pdb
│   Qt6QmlWorkerScriptd.dll
│   Qt6QmlWorkerScriptd.pdb
│   Qt6Quick.dll
│   Qt6Quick.pdb
│   Qt6Quick3D.pdb
│   Qt6Quick3DAssetImport.pdb
│   Qt6Quick3DAssetImportd.pdb
│   Qt6Quick3Dd.pdb
│   Qt6Quick3DIblBaker.pdb
│   Qt6Quick3DIblBakerd.pdb
│   Qt6Quick3DParticles.pdb
│   Qt6Quick3DParticlesd.pdb
│   Qt6Quick3DRuntimeRender.pdb
│   Qt6Quick3DRuntimeRenderd.pdb
│   Qt6Quick3DUtils.pdb
│   Qt6Quick3DUtilsd.pdb
│   Qt6QuickControls2.dll
│   Qt6QuickControls2.pdb
│   Qt6QuickControls2d.dll
│   Qt6QuickControls2d.pdb
│   Qt6QuickControls2Impl.dll
│   Qt6QuickControls2Impl.pdb
│   Qt6QuickControls2Impld.dll
│   Qt6QuickControls2Impld.pdb
│   Qt6Quickd.dll
│   Qt6Quickd.pdb
│   Qt6QuickLayouts.dll
│   Qt6QuickLayouts.pdb
│   Qt6QuickLayoutsd.dll
│   Qt6QuickLayoutsd.pdb
│   Qt6QuickParticles.dll
│   Qt6QuickParticles.pdb
│   Qt6QuickParticlesd.dll
│   Qt6QuickParticlesd.pdb
│   Qt6QuickShapes.dll
│   Qt6QuickShapes.pdb
│   Qt6QuickShapesd.dll
│   Qt6QuickShapesd.pdb
│   Qt6QuickTemplates2.dll
│   Qt6QuickTemplates2.pdb
│   Qt6QuickTemplates2d.dll
│   Qt6QuickTemplates2d.pdb
│   Qt6QuickTest.dll
│   Qt6QuickTest.pdb
│   Qt6QuickTestd.dll
│   Qt6QuickTestd.pdb
│   Qt6QuickWidgets.dll
│   Qt6QuickWidgets.pdb
│   Qt6QuickWidgetsd.dll
│   Qt6QuickWidgetsd.pdb
│   Qt6Scxml.dll
│   Qt6Scxml.pdb
│   Qt6Scxmld.dll
│   Qt6Scxmld.pdb
│   Qt6ScxmlQml.dll
│   Qt6ScxmlQml.pdb
│   Qt6ScxmlQmld.dll
│   Qt6ScxmlQmld.pdb
│   Qt6ShaderTools.dll
│   Qt6ShaderTools.pdb
│   Qt6ShaderToolsd.dll
│   Qt6ShaderToolsd.pdb
│   Qt6Sql.dll
│   Qt6Sql.pdb
│   Qt6Sqld.dll
│   Qt6Sqld.pdb
│   Qt6StateMachine.dll
│   Qt6StateMachine.pdb
│   Qt6StateMachined.dll
│   Qt6StateMachined.pdb
│   Qt6StateMachineQml.dll
│   Qt6StateMachineQml.pdb
│   Qt6StateMachineQmld.dll
│   Qt6StateMachineQmld.pdb
│   Qt6Svg.dll
│   Qt6Svg.pdb
│   Qt6Svgd.dll
│   Qt6Svgd.pdb
│   Qt6SvgWidgets.dll
│   Qt6SvgWidgets.pdb
│   Qt6SvgWidgetsd.dll
│   Qt6SvgWidgetsd.pdb
│   Qt6Test.dll
│   Qt6Test.pdb
│   Qt6Testd.dll
│   Qt6Testd.pdb
│   Qt6UiTools.dll
│   Qt6UiTools.pdb
│   Qt6UiToolsd.dll
│   Qt6UiToolsd.pdb
│   Qt6VirtualKeyboard.dll
│   Qt6VirtualKeyboard.pdb
│   Qt6VirtualKeyboardd.dll
│   Qt6VirtualKeyboardd.pdb
│   Qt6Widgets.dll
│   Qt6Widgets.pdb
│   Qt6Widgetsd.dll
│   Qt6Widgetsd.pdb
│   Qt6Xml.dll
│   Qt6Xml.pdb
│   Qt6Xmld.dll
│   Qt6Xmld.pdb
│   qtattributionsscanner.exe
│   qtattributionsscanner.pdb
│   qtdiag.exe
│   qtdiag.pdb
│   qtdiag6.exe
│   QtJambi3DAnimation6.dll
│   QtJambi3DCore6.dll
│   QtJambi3DLogic6.dll
│   QtJambi3DQuick6.dll
│   QtJambi3DQuickScene2D6.dll
│   QtJambi3DRender6.dll
│   QtJambi6.dll
│   QtJambiCharts6.dll
│   QtJambiConcurrent6.dll
│   QtJambiCore6.dll
│   QtJambiDataVisualization6.dll
│   QtJambiDBus6.dll
│   QtJambiDesigner6.dll
│   QtJambiGui6.dll
│   QtJambiHelp6.dll
│   QtJambiNetwork6.dll
│   QtJambiNetworkAuth6.dll
│   QtJambiOpenGL6.dll
│   QtJambiOpenGLWidgets6.dll
│   QtJambiPrintSupport6.dll
│   QtJambiQml6.dll
│   QtJambiQuick3D6.dll
│   QtJambiQuick6.dll
│   QtJambiQuickControls26.dll
│   QtJambiQuickWidgets6.dll
│   QtJambiScxml6.dll
│   QtJambiSql6.dll
│   QtJambiStateMachine6.dll
│   QtJambiSvg6.dll
│   QtJambiSvgWidgets6.dll
│   QtJambiTest6.dll
│   QtJambiUiTools6.dll
│   QtJambiVirtualKeyboard6.dll
│   QtJambiWidgets6.dll
│   QtJambiXml6.dll
│   qtpaths.exe
│   qtpaths.pdb
│   qtplugininfo.exe
│   qtplugininfo.pdb
│   qtquickcontrols2implplugin.dll
│   qtquickcontrols2implplugind.dll
│   qvkgen.exe
│   qvkgen.pdb
│   rcc.exe
│   rcc.pdb
│   shadergen.pdb
│   syncqt.pl
│   testcon.exe
│   tracegen.exe
│   tracegen.pdb
│   uic.exe
│   uic.pdb
│   windeployqt.exe
│   windeployqt.pdb
```

I use runtime parametr for classpath
`-Djava.library.path=C:\Qt\jBin\bin;C:\Qt\6.1.0\msvc2019_64\bin`

jBin folder contains all `.jar` files for QT. Here my code:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        QtUtilities.initializePackage("io.qt.network");
        QtUtilities.initializePackage("io.qt.quick");
        QtUtilities.loadQtLibrary("QuickShapes");
        QtUtilities.loadQtLibrary("QuickTemplates2");
        QtUtilities.loadQtLibrary("QuickParticles");
        QtUtilities.loadQtLibrary("QuickControls2");

        QCoreApplication.setAttribute(Qt.ApplicationAttribute.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
        QGuiApplication qGuiApplication = QGuiApplication.initialize(args);
        QQuickView view = new QQuickView();
        view.engine().addImportPath("StorageScanner/imports");
        view.setSource(QUrl.fromLocalFile("StorageScanner/StorageScanner.qml"));
        if (!view.errors().isEmpty()){
            view.errors().forEach(qQmlError -> {
                System.err.println(qQmlError.toString());
            });
            throw new RuntimeException("Resource load failed");
        }
        view.show();
        QGuiApplication.exec();
    }
```

But I always got an error:

```
file:///.../QtTest/StorageScanner/StorageScanner.qml:9:5: Type Screen01 unavailable
file:///.../QtTest/StorageScanner/Screen01.ui.qml:2:1: Cannot load library C:\Qt\6.1.0\msvc2019_64\qml\QtQuick\Controls\impl\qtquickcontrols2implplugin.dll: The specified module could not be found.
file:///.../QtTest/StorageScanner/Screen01.ui.qml: Failed to load dependencies for module "QtQuick.Controls" version 2.15
```

The DLL is at the specified path. How do I fix that? Thanks in advice!